# if $g$ is continuous, then $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-L}^L g(x,t) \, dx = \int_{-L}^L \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \, dx $

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

> Show that if $g$ is continuous, then:
>   \begin{align*}
>   \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{-L}^L g(x,t) \, dx &= \int_{-L}^L \frac{\partial g}{\partial t} \, dx \\
> \end{align*}

My PDE textbook presents this as a given, and I'd like to see the proof.

By @cmk's advice, I can apply the difference quotient definition of the derivative to yield:

\begin{align*}
  \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} \left[ \left( \int_{-L}^L g(x,t+h) \, dx \right) - \left( \int_{-L}^L g(x,t) \, dx \right) \right] &= \int_{-L}^L \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{1}{h} [g(x,t + h) - g(x,t)] \, dx \\  
\end{align*}

I'm not sure how to go from there.

Comment: What have you tried? What happens if you look at the difference quotient?

Comment: I tried that and put that in the OP. Any further hints?

Comment: The limit on the RHS inside the integral is precisely the partial derivative $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial t}(x,t)$, but the question is why can you bring the limit inside the integral?